# XPath difference between child::* and child::node()

Tags: xml, xpath

Is there a difference between the following two xpath expressions?

- `child::*`
- `child::node()`

I tried both expressions on [this](https://scrapinghub.github.io/xpath-playground/) playground page and got the same result.

[W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) says

> `child::*` Selects all element children of the current node
>
> `child::node()` Selects all children of the current node

but I do not get the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `child::*` and `child::node()` refer to the *children* of the current node, so the difference is really in the difference between that of an ***element*** (for which `*` selects any), and a ***node*** (for which `node()` selects any).

### An *element* is a type of *node*.

XPath has the following node types in its model of XML:

- element
- attribute
- text
- namespace
- processing instruction (PI)
- comment
- root

For your example XML / HTML,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Welcome to my <a href="#">page</a></h2>
        <p>This is the first paragraph</p>.
        <!-- this is the end -->
    </body>
</html>
```

there are `count(//*)` = 7 elements and `count(//node())` = 21 nodes.

Your playground XPath is `//h2/a`, which doesn't really illustrate `child::*` vs `child::node()`.

If instead you consider `//h2/*` vs `//h2/node()`, then

- `//h2/*` selects a single *node*, an *element*:

  ```
    <a href="#">page</a>
  ```
- `//h2/node()` selects two *nodes*, a *text* node and an *element*:

  ```
    Welcome to my
    <a href="#">page</a>
  ```