# Using XPATH, how to select ANY node that contains a certain string

Tags: xml, xpath, contains

Let's say I have an XML file like this one:

```
<books>
  <book>
    <title>John is alive</title>
    <abstract>
        A man is found alive after having disappeared for 10 years.
    </abstract>
    <description>
        <en> John disappeared 10 years ago. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...</en>
        <fr> Il y a 10 ans, John disparaissait. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...</fr>
    </description>
    <notes>First book in the series, where the character is introduced</notes>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title>The disappearance of John</title>
    <abstract>
        A prequel to the book "John is alive".
    </abstract>
    <description>
        <en> He lead an ordinary life, but then ... lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...</en>
        <fr> Sa vie était tout à fait ordinaire, mais ... lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...</fr>
    </description>
    <notes>Second book in the "John" series, but first in chronological order</notes>
  </book>
</books>
```

My question is simple: **how can I, using XPATH, get a collection of all nodes that contain the word `John`?**

Obviously, I can specify a series of nodes and that works fine:

`(//title | //abstract | //description/* | //notes)[contains(lower-case(text()),"john")]`

But if my XML grows (and it will!), with new elements being added at various levels in the structure, I don't want to constantly have to go back and adjust my XPATH.

What I fail to understand is why a generic statement like

`//*[contains(lower-case(text()),"john")]`

fails with this error message `Required cardinality of first argument of lower-case() is one or zero`.

Yet, not all statements with an asterisk fail.

For instance:

`//books/book/*[contains(lower-case(text()),"john")]` fails with the above error message

while

`//books/book/*/*[contains(lower-case(text()),"john")]` succeeds and retrieves both the `<en>` and `<fr>` nodes from the first `<description>` element

If it's not possible, fine, I will list all elements in my XPATH, but I still would like to get a clear understanding of the behavior of the `*` selector in the context of a `contains()` operation.

Comment: What's your XPath version and environment. Works for me in XPath2.0 https://cutt.ly/UjLvEtI

Comment: Am using XPath 2.0, as evidenced by the lower-case() statements. But anyway, @kjhughes gave me the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some ambiguity regarding the term *nodes* (see [XPath difference between child::* and child::node()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52045856/290085)) and the term *contains* (see [How to use XPath contains() for specific text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39650007/290085)) when being less than perfectly precise, but one of the following XPaths will likely meet your needs:

1. All *nodes* whose [string value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) contains the substring, `"John"`:

   ```
   //node()[contains(.,"John")]
   ```
2. All such *elements*:

   ```
   //*[contains(.,"John")]
   ```
3. All such *attributes*:

   ```
   //@*[contains(.,"John")]
   ```
4. All such *text nodes*:

   ```
   //text()[contains(.,"John")]
   ```
5. All *elements* with text node children that contain the substring, `"John"`:

   ```
   //*[text()[contains(.,"John")]]
   ```

Notice that #1 will include `books`, but #5 will exclude it.  See [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085).

You can replace `contains(.,"John")` with `contains(lower-case(.),"john")` in any of the above XPaths if you're using XPath 2.0.  See also [Case insensitive XPath contains() possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8474031/290085)

Comment: Number 4 and/or Number 5 are exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know about the //text() construct, that's going to be very valuable in the future. Thanks!