# Why does XPath contains() select an unexpected node?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to find the correct XPath expression to get only URLs from all my documents, whatever the tag is. I'm trying with this one :

```
<urlset xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://url
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2019-08-07T15:01:51+00:00
    </lastmod>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

The following expression gives me these results :

```
//*[contains(.,'http')]//text()
```

1. `https://url`
2. `2019-08-07T15:01:51+00:00`

What I'm looking for is to get rid of the second line. I need to be able to get **only URLs** from any XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your XPath,

```
//*[contains(.,'http')]//text()
```

selects a surprise second result is that this XPath says to select all elements whose [*string-value*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) contains an `"http"` substring, and return all descendant text nodes.  These elements include not just the immediate parent element of the targeted text node but its ancestors as well:

1. The `loc` element, as you expected.
2. The `urlset` and `url` too, as you did not expect.  (The `urlset` and `url` elements also have a `2019-08-07T15:01:51+00:00` descendant text node, and thus as part of their *string-values*.)

### Alternatives to achieve desired result

- Narrow the `*` all-elements wildcard to a single, named element:

  ```
  //loc[contains(.,'http')]/text()
  ```
- Narrow the `*` all-elements wildcard to multiple, named elements:

  ```
  //*[(self::loc or self::e2) and contains(.,'http')]/text()
  ```
- Select all text nodes containing the substring, `"http"` [as noted by Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70582062/290085):

  ```
  //text()[contains(., 'http')]
  ```

### See also

- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)
- [Using XPATH, how to select ANY node that contains a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65850091/290085)
- [How to use XPath contains() for specific text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39650007/290085)

Comment: Thank you. I already watched these topics but didn't found the right syntax I searched for (which is the last one). The problem I'm facing is that I'm not sure about the tags I will find on my xml document. That's why I need to search in the text whatever the tag is. And I'm not sure if your first and second alternatives work if there isn't any <loc> tag in my xml (and I'm totally curious to know why if I'm wrong).

Comment: The first and second alternatives do presume the existence of the named elements.  Keep in mind that well-designed markup obviates the need to pattern match on text as the whole point of markup is to identify document parts.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's ignore the fact that not all URLs contain "http" and not everything that contains "http" is a URL...

To find all text nodes containing "http", just use `//text()[contains(., 'http')]`.

Comment: Could it be more reasonable if I use www ?

Comment: I can't tell what's reasonable for you - you know your data, I don't. Detecting relative URIs like 'index.html' is difficult! Usually it's better to take advantage of the XML tagging rather than rely on matching the content.

Comment: I'm ok with you. I just don't know in advance the tags I will find. But thank you btw it helped me.